# tensorflow count number of 0 at index 2 in a flatten-batch

Tags: tensorflow

Sorry for the inaccurate title. Here is the detail description of the problem: assume a tensor of shape `(?, 2)`, e.g., a tensor **T** `[[0,1], [0,2], [0,0], [1, 4], [1, 3], [2,0], [2,0], [2,0],[2,0]]`. How to count how many zero showing up for every `T[:, 0]`. For the example above, because there is `[0,0]` and `[2,0]`, the answer is 2.

More examples:

1. `[[0,1], [0,2], [0,1], [1, 4], [1, 3], [2,0], [2,0], [2,0],[2,0]]` (Answer: 1, because of `[2,0]`)
2. `[[0,1], [0,2], [0,1], [1, 4], [1, 3], [2,0], [2,0], [2,0],[2,0],[3,0]]` (Answer: 2, because of `[2, 0]` and `[3,0]`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got what you are looking for, the question is how many unique "[X, 0]-pairs" you have in the data. If so, this should do it:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.placeholder(shape=(None, 2), dtype=tf.int32)
indices = tf.where(tf.equal(x[:,1], tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32)))
unique_values, _ = tf.unique(tf.squeeze(tf.gather(x[:, 0], indices)))
no_unique_values = tf.shape(unique_values, out_type=tf.int32)

data = [ .... ]

with tf.Session() as sess:
    no_unique = sess.run(fetches=[no_unique_values], feed_dict={x: data})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution I got myself

```
def get_unique(ts):
    ts_part = ts[:, 1]
    where = tf.where(tf.equal(0, ts_part))
    gather_nd = tf.gather_nd(ts, where)
    gather_plus = gather_nd[:, 0] + gather_nd[:, 1]
    unique_values, _ = tf.unique(gather_plus)
    return tf.shape(unique_values)[0]
```